# How many people follow me on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I would like to know how many of my friends follow me on Facebook. I have looked up my profile on other peoples Facebook accounts and try to log on to my account through a computer for room and yet I still am unable to find out how many followers I have.

Answer (score 2):

From [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/139647049460999):

> ### How do I see who is following me?
>
> If you've allowed people to follow you, you can see a list of your followers:
>
> 1. Go to your profile.
> 2. Click **Friends** below your cover photo.
> 3. Click **Followers**. If no one is following you yet, you won't see this option.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Facebook Followers tab]

You can directly access the page at this URI: `https://www.facebook.com/<username>/followers`